# Need help displaying different footer widgets in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

For all those wordpress users out there!

I'm putting together a wordpress theme and I have 4 widget areas in the footer. What I want to do is if there is no 4th widget set in wordpress that the 3rd widget area expand the size of the 4th too.

OR

Is there a way to have my 4 widgets on the home page and then in all other pages 4 completely different widgets?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Don't put them in the footer.  Create 2 page templates, one with 4 sidebar areas and one with 3.  Then on the homepage use that template and the other pages use the other template.